# Google drive get list of users for an ID using a Server API Key

Tags: google-drive-api

How do I elevate writes to a server API Key so that it can get all user's groups?

I get a 403 permissions error whenever I try it. Which makes me think I'm missing some step where I give the API Key admin rights.

I have navigated in the Google api console every which way and I cannot find a way to assign group directory list authority to a user.

Anyone know how to assign this ability to list a given Google apps user's groups?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What is the use of Server key here?

Comment: I have a java web app that runs on a server. This has a google api key on the server. I want that key to have permission to list any user's groups. Can it be done?